# Rewriting Creation and Annihilation Operators

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-hall-effect

I am playing with the Landau Level problem and Algebraic solutions to it. I am given 
$$a=\frac{l_{b}}{\sqrt{2}\hbar}(\pi_{x}-i\pi_{y}) ~~~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~~~~a^{\dagger}=\frac{l_{b}}{\sqrt{2}\hbar}(\pi_{x}+i\pi_{y})$$

The creation and annihilation operators. I am told that I can express these in terms of $x$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $k$, but am unsure how to proceed. Would I just expand every term and substitute? That seems like a lot of work that may be unnecessary. $\pi$ is the kinetic momentum.

Comment: For context, I am studying the quantum Hall Effect, integer and fractional, and this came up in my instructors online notes. I am unsure why you would rewrite this, and further what is the best way to approach it. To expand on my idea, I was thinking to expand $\pi$ to $\vec{\pi}=m\vec{v}=\vec{p}-\frac{q}{c}\vec{A}$ and perhaps try from there.

Comment: Perhaps you know something about the commutation relations that could help you rewrite these?  How are the momentum and position operators related?

Comment: Great call, hadn't even considered it in my foolishness. $$[p_{i},r_{j}]=[p_{i},r_{j}]=-i\hbar \delta_{ij}$$ $$[R_{i},\pi_{j}]=0$$ $$[\pi_{i},\pi_{j}]=-i \epsilon_{ij} m \hbar \omega_{c}=-i \epsilon_{ij} \frac{\hbar^{2}}{l_{b}^{2}}$$ $$[R_{i},R_{j}]=i \epsilon_{ij} l_{b}^{2}$$ $$[\rho_{i},\rho_{j}]=-i \epsilon_{ij} l_{b}^{2}$$ $$[\rho_{i},\pi_{j}]=i \hbar \delta_{ij}$$ $$[p_{i},\pi_{j}]=-i \hbar \frac{e}{c} \frac{\partial A_{j}}{\partial r_{i}}$$ $$[R_{i},r_{j}]=i \epsilon_{ij} l_{b}^{2}$$ $$[\rho_{i},r_{j}]=-i \epsilon_{ij} l_{b}^{2}$$

Comment: When you have factors of $k$, it usually comes from taking derivatives of an assumed plane-wave solution... does that help?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't.

Comment: Do you know anything about the commutation of $a$ and $a^\dagger$?

Comment: of course, it is 1. $$[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7543/discussion-between-kdn-and-dylan-sabulsky)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we choose a gauge.  We will use the Landau gauage, so that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=B_z x \mathbf{\hat{y}}
\end{equation}
corrseponding to a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}=B_z \mathbf{\hat{z}}$.

With this choice of gauge, the kinetic momentum operators can be rewritten in terms of the canonical momentum operators, as
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \pi_x &= p_x - \frac{e}{c} A_x = p_x\\
    \pi_y &= p_y - \frac{e}{c} A_y = p_y - \frac{e B_z x}{c}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
If we write down the Hamiltonian in these terms,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2 m}\left(\mathbf{p}-\frac{e}{c}\mathbf{A}\right)^2
\end{equation}
we see that, since $\mathbf{A}$ has no $y$ dependence, the canonical $p_y$ operator commutes with the Hamiltonian.  We may therefore replace it with its eigenvalue, $\hbar k_y$.
Rewriting the momentum operator in terms of the position operator, the creation operator may be written
\begin{equation}
a^\dagger=\frac{l_b}{\sqrt{2} \hbar}(\pi_x+i\pi_y)=\frac{l_b}{\sqrt{2} \hbar}\left( \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\hbar k_y - \frac{e}{c}B_z x\right),
\end{equation}
which rewrites this operator in terms of your chosen variables.

Different gauge choices can be made, preserving translational or rotational invariance.  This particular gauge choice preserves translation invariance along the $y$-axis.  For a more detailed discussion of this topic, see [these lecture notes](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221A-F04/Landau.pdf).